# How to get length of shellcode string containing NULL characters

Tags: c++, string, shellcode

I have string of shellcode with NULL characters in between them and i am unable to detect its length, i tried `std::string.length()` method but it only counts till NULL character after that it doesn't count.

Here is sample code .

```
   std::string shell_str = "\x55\x48\x89\x00\x00\x00\x00\xC3\x90";
   std::cout << "shell : " << shell_str << std::endl;     
   std::cout << "shell length : " << shell_str.length() << std::endl;
```

***Output*** : 
`shell : UH�` 
`shell length : 3`

**But length of string is 9** and i tried to copy it to vector also but still doesn't get the desired output .

Full code snippet is posted [here](https://ideone.com/l0Mv18)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't with the calculation of the length of `shell_str`, the problem is with the literal string you use to initialize `shell_str`. The constructor of `std::string` will stop at the "terminator".

You need to use another [`std::string` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), to explicitly tell it the actual length of the string:

```
std::string shell_str("\x55\x48\x89\x00\x00\x00\x00\xC3\x90", 9);
```

---

Also, since the "string" contains arbitrary data, you can't print it as a string either.

And if you want a "string" of arbitrary bytes I suggest you use `std::vector<uint8_t>` instead.

Comment: I tried using **_vector<uint8_t>_**  and i got this **error: conversion from 'const char [10]' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<unsigned char>' requested**

Comment: @HaSeeBMiR `uint8_t` is defined as `unsigned char` in your compiler which is not the same as `char`. You need to cast your array/string to `uint8_t*` or use `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: @NO_NAME but the string literal is const char* its better to use uint8_t array rather than vector because it needs conversion .

Comment: @HaSeeBMiR You might be using a string literal for the initialization, but it's really a different way of representing an array of unsigned bytes (unsigned because otherwise those `"\x89"` and `"\xC3"` and `"\x90"` will not be what you think).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude why vector<uint8_t> is preferred here why can't we use uint8_t array (old C-style array) or some unsigned string like **typedef basic_string<uint8_t> ustring**

Comment: @HaSeeBMiR Well if the size is fixed at time of compilation, you could use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) I guess. But a C-style array have some drawbacks, like just about all the time you need the size of the array it has decayed to a pointer and the size is no longer available. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but my shellcode is compile time constant it won’t grow or shrink to I don’t think using vector here is a good choice maybe std::array or uint8_t array will do the job here.